# .NET Runtime 2.0 Error

Tags: .net

I keep on getting .NET Runtime 2.0 Errors (reported in the Event Log) on my test machines, I tend to get these when swapping assemblies out for those with more debugging / diagnostic information (or fixes). An example message:

```
Faulting application MyApp.exe, version 1.0.0.66, stamp 4a3851fa, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.2.3790.4480, stamp 49c51f0a, debug? 0, fault address 0x0000bef7.
```

My guess is that even though I'm careful not to alter the interface, swapping assemblies in this way is probaly something I shouldnt be doing (should I be doing this?)

All the same, the instalation / Build process for this app is hefty, and its a massive pain to rebuild and reinstall everything when debugging problems (in fact its just not fesable). Is there any way to get any more useful information out of these sorts of errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the application encountering an unhandled exception.

Although it may be more work in the short run, you could rework your application to include tracing information and to use the tools provided in the [System.Diagnostics namespace.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.aspx)

For example, [System.Diagnostics.Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) allows you to specify via configuration (no change in build) different listener classes that could be used for runtime tracing.  You could use this to implement functionality that would at least help you narrow down what might be causing your issues, and only enable the tracing output on your test machines.

Also, make sure you have a clean, top level exception handler.  That may help you at least discover some of your stack trace information when your application faults.

Answer (score 0):

Old post but I just had this problem and was able to track down the offending code by remote debugging as described here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146838/Remote-debugging-with-Visual-Studio-2010#_rating

similar question here: 
[.NET Winforms app dies on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154079/net-winforms-app-dies-on-startup)

In my case I had a hanlder for a treeview AfterSelect which was was changing the selection of the tree and causing another AfterSelect to be called, etc - the resulting error: stackoverflow. This doesn't seem to happen on other machines so might be something to do with the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a console application; I solved it by launching it from the command line, where I could see the cause of the error (in my case, access rights on a DLL) :

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file
or assembly 'FHVI_Common, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' 
or one of its dependencies. Access is denied. File name: 'FHVI_Common, Version=1.1.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException:  
    Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
    at xyzCL_Process.Main()
```