# .NET Winforms app dies on startup

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a .NET Winforms app written in C# which works everywhere but on one particular machine.  On that machine it dies without ever starting.  There is no error message, but the following is written to the event log:

> Type: Error
>
> Source: .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting
>
> Description: Faulting application myapp.exe, version 4.2.0.0, stamp 4bcf05d0, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.2.3790.4480, stamp 49c51f0a, debug? 0, fault address 0x0000bef7.

There doesn't seem to be anything odd about that machine - it is one of a number of clones created with VSphere, and doesn't exhibit any other issues.  The other clones run my app without any problem.  It is Windows Server 2003 SP2 with .NET Framework 3.5 SP1, running Citrix, which was reinstalled after the clone to take the new name (as were the other clones).

Any advice on how to diagnose or trap the issue?

Also, I am soon going to release a new version of my app, is there anything I can do to the new version to give more information on this kind of problem?

---

EDIT:  Thank you all for your answers, unfortunately the sysadmins for the machine decided to just rebuild it from scratch, and the problem went away.  So I'll probably never know what the problem was.

Comment: Have you tried running the application from the Command Prompt? Sometimes error messages are only displayed there.

Comment: Is your app compiled with .NET Framework 2.0 or 3.5 SP1 ?

Comment: @dtb I will ask them to try that now.  @Stefan P. .NET Framework 3.5 SP1

Comment: @dtb thank you, unfortunately, no messages of any kind display at the command prompt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install Debugging tools for Windows on that machine, and use WinDbg to launch your application. Then it should tell what exceptions happen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this is a production server and the admins are reluctant for now.  I shall bear this in mind in case it becomes more urgent (or the machine is retired from production).

Comment: Debugging Tools for Windows can also be first installed on another machine (same bitness) and then (the whole installation folder) copied to this production one.

Comment: I wasn't able to try your answer in the end, but I've accepted it as being the most likely to be useful in this and similar situations.

Comment: remove debugging helped me with this - I followed the instructions here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146838/Remote-debugging-with-Visual-Studio-2010

Answer (score 1):

If the error is related to environment (such as missing assembly) then the app will not reach a point where you can trap & log it.

I would create a new console application and then load such app into new AppDomain and run it with ExecuteAssembly. If the errors are .NET exceptions you will be able to catch them and write to a console window.

Comment: Thanks, I shall have a go at writing this and see if the admins will let me run it.

Answer (score 0):

Is your MyApp.Exe.Config a correct XML file? Open it in Visual Studio, and see if there are any errors against the XML format.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this didn't solve it.  The .config validates in Visual Studio, and I have also tried reinstalling the app (thereby returning to defaults) and replacing it with the default file from another server which is working.

Comment: Too bad, I've had a few cases where this was the problem for symptoms like yours.